# Not allowing scroll past a fixed height when an element is present on the screen

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a page that has an approximate height of 5000px, quite a long page. When clicking a button an overlay appears that starts at the top of the page and is about 2000px in height. I would like to have it so that when the overlay is on the screen the user cannot scroll past 2000px.

I looked around and most of the suggests pointed me to particular situations of scrolling and now exactly what I wanted. Any suggestions?

Comment: what about detach elements and reappend them when needed?

Comment: Since the overlay is transparent I want the content to appear to still be behind it. But for the page to stop scrolling and to cut off at 2000px.

Comment: I don't know what your specific need is, but maybe you could set the overflow on the page to hidden (so it won't scroll) and make the overlay fill the window with overflow auto.  Though, it would cause the window to resize slightly when the scrollbar goes away.

Comment: could this fit your needs, classic way: http://jsfiddle.net/eRLAM/

Comment: that's actually pretty good, but out of curiosity is there anyway for the page to recognize that the scroll bar ends at that point? So that the user won't get confused why they cannot scroll any further with the scroll bar having space at the bottom